# How to display borders in thead with border-collapse?

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

I would like to collapse only the out-side border, not inside of the thead:

```css
table, tr {
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 7px;
            border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
            background: #ccccff;
        }
```

```html
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Data 1</th>
                <th>Data 2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
 </table>
```

will not show the borders between the `th` like `Data 1 | Data 2`, why? (And how to add these the border between the `th` elements)?

Comment: Did you want the whole table to have borders (including the outside), or *just* the inner cells with no border around the outside of the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `border: 1px solid black` from `table, tr`. And set the border for the right side `border-right: 1px solid black`. Also, using the `:last-of-type` pseudo-class, remove the border for the last element.

```css
table, tr {
            /*border: 1px solid black;*/
            padding: 7px;
            border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
            background: #ccccff;
            border-right: 1px solid black;
        }
        
th:last-of-type {
            border-right: unset;
        }
```

```html
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Data 1</th>
                <th>Data 2</th>
                <th>Data 3</th>
                <th>Data 4</th>
                <th>Data 5</th>
                <th>Data 6</th>
                <th>Data 7</th>
                <th>Data 8</th>
                <th>Data 9</th>
                <th>Data 10</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

`border-collapse` doesn't have the effect you think. It just prevents gaps *between* the borders of each cell. This is what happens without border-collapse:

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 7px;
  border-collapse: none;
}

th,td {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Data 1</th>
      <th>Data 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

The other problem is that you are adding the border to the `tr` - this is just the row, it doesn't apply to the cells inside the row.  Also FYI, adding a border to the table in CSS only adds the border around the outside of the whole table.

**To apply borders to the cells**, you need to add the border CSS to the `th` elements (and `td` for the rest of your table), e.g.:

```
th, td {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

**Working Snippet** with examples of just rows with borders and `th`/`td`s with borders:

```css
table,
tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 7px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align:center;
}

th {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

tr.showborder td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Data 1</th>
      <th>Data 2</th>
      <th>Data 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>this ROW</td>
      <td> has a</td>
      <td>border</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>this ROW</td>
      <td> also has a</td>
      <td>border</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="showborder">
      <td>The cells in </td>
      <td>this row all</td>
      <td>have borders</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="showborder">
      <td>The cells in </td>
      <td>this row all</td>
      <td>have borders</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```